# Почему переменная d = d*2 при печати на экран выдает разные значения?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!
Учу C++ и решил поэкспериментировать создал переменную d, которая равна d*2, в коде выглядит так - `int d = d*2;` 
Кроме неё у меня есть еще 3 переменных - `a, b, c`.

```
int a = 4 + 5;
int b = 31 - 6;
int c = 1;
```

Далее я вывожу эту переменную на экран
`cout <<"d: "<< d << endl;`
А также остальные три:

```
cout <<"a: "<< a << endl;
cout <<"b: "<< b << endl;
cout <<"c: "<< c << endl;
```

И каждый раз получаю какие-то разные значения, например `d: 1912095712` или `d: 835226272` (и другие 3 переменных). Что это за числа (в случаи с переменной d)? Откуда они берутся? Почему программа не выдает мне ошибку, ведь я вовсе не знаю чему равна `d`? Связано ли это с уделеннием оперативной памяти на мою переменную (переменная int занимает 4 байта) или же с путем размещения переменной? 
Возможно ли такое "явление" в других языках программирования?
Также попробовал убрать остальные переменные (переменные `a, b, c`) и стал получать значение переменной `d` ноль! Есть ли связь между переменной `d` и другими тремя?
Полностью код выглядит так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int a = 4 + 5;
  int b = 31 - 6;
  int c = 1;
  int d = d*2;
  cout <<"a: "<< a << endl;
  cout <<"b: "<< b << endl;
  cout <<"c: "<< c << endl; 
  cout <<"d: "<< d << endl;
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша переменная просто инициализирована некоторым случайным содержимым памяти. Компилятор должен был предупредить вас об этом - так, VC++ 2017 сообщает:

> warning C4700: использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "d"

Answer (score 3):

Потому что не инициализированная переменная может содержать любой мусор, который вы умножаете на 2 и выводите.